# Concatenate array into string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this:

```
var myarray = [];
myarray ["first"] = "$firstelement";
myarray ["second"] = "$secondelement";
```

And I want to get the string:

```
"first":"$firstelement","second": "$secondelement"
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is invalid *(even if it works)*, arrays don't have named keys, but numeric indexes.

You should be using an object instead, and if you want a string, you can stringify it as JSON

```js
var myobject = {};
myobject["first"] = "$firstelement";
myobject["second"] = "$secondelement";

var str = JSON.stringify(myobject);

console.log(str)
```

Comment: ok but I do not want `{}` around the string and also do not want double `"` inside string

Comment: This is what you should want, as it's valid JSON. You can remove the curlybraces with `.slice(1, -1)` and you could replace the quotes with `.replace(/\"/,'')` but you shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd want to use an object instead of an array:

```
var myarray = {}; // not []
myarray ["first"] = "$firstelement";
myarray ["second"] = "$secondelement";
```

The easiest way, then, to achieve what you want is to use JSON:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myarray);
var arrayString = jsonString.slice(1, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

```js
var myarray = {};
myarray ["first"] = "$firstelement";
myarray ["second"] = "$secondelement";

console.log(JSON.stringify(myarray));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.strinify()

`JSON.stringify(item)`